# What does this sed command do?

Tags: sed

i searched long for this but i could not figure out what this sed actually does!?

```
sed -E $'s:$:\t:' < file1 | cut -f 2 > file2
```

Who can explain me please?

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: Instead of searching for a solution, search for the documentation for `sed` and read it.  Then you will be able to explain it yourself ... AND understand other things that `sed` can do.

Comment: FWIW, it's a substitution that appends a tab character to the end of each line. Then `cut`s out the second field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a sed script, it's a shell script containing bash, sed, and cut commands. The sed script is obfuscated by bad quoting practices, unnecessarily changing the delimiter, and adding an unnecessary argument. I assume you know what `cut -f 2` does so I can't imagine why you included that to further obfuscate your question and so I'm going to ignore it and focus on the sed part.

The command you have is:

```
sed -E $'s:$:\t:'
```

Let's rewrite that sensibly and you get:

```
sed 's/$/'$'\t''/'
```

which without the `'` script delimiters and with some extra white space added for clarity is:

```
s/  $  /  $'\t' /
```

Now do you see what it's doing? Replacing the end-of-line with a tab.

Comment: So in the end it was something very simple ... Thank you for your reply :)